# Hiding bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am in problem to complete my PhD thesis in Lyx/tex. The bibliography style of my university doesn't match with any available style file. I want to manually correct the bibliography file add as a pdf file in the Lyx/tex. In response to my last question the answer was good but I am not capable to use biblatex.
I want to know how should I keep the citations in the text without generating bibliography. My references database is in bib format. The citation style is author year.
I shall appreciate to have probable solution.

Comment: You could try `\usepackage{bibentry}` and then `\nobibliography{mybib}` instead of `\bibliography`. But probably it would be easier to correct at the end the .bbl-file (make sure that you don't call bibtex afterwards). You could also try makebst to create a working style. Or make a effort to get biblatex working ...

Comment: Are you able to manually delete the pages that contain the bibliography from the pdf output file?

Comment: The problem is partially solved and thanks for that. If I use bib entry package and no bibliography command it suppress bibliography but the pdf output does not show any citations, it shows only question signs. I need to show Author year style. Is there any way pl. let me know.

Comment: Is there any way to show header in a chapter which consists of added pdf of multiple pages?